# App keeps stopping after react-native-rename and Missing MainApplication.java and MainActivity.java

Tags: android, react-native

How can i get back my MainApplication.java and MainActivity.java??

I want to change my app name, so i used react-native-rename. But after that the compiler gave errors and i've tried many times until build success. yes the build succeed but the app keep stopping :') and i looked at my MainApplication.java, and i realized it's missing already. Please what should i do :((

i used

> `"react": "^16.5.0", 
>    "react-native": "0.57.4",`